# Microsoft stream video is coming as white space in IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have added one content editor webpart in my sharepoint page and added Microsoft stream video embedded code there. Its displaying properly in every browser except IE11. Its coming as white blank space. Any idea how to fix it ??